# On Stein&Shakarchi's discussion on the "uniqueness of Fourier series"

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I'm reading Stein&Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis: An Introduction*. Section 2 of Chapter 2 has the title of "Uniqueness of Fourier series". However, after thinking about the results given there, it seems to me this title is misleading. Because the aim of this section is to establish, in a rough sense, the following

> If $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier coefficients, then $f$ and $g$ are necessarily equal.

So the title should be "**Uniqueness of limit functions of Fourier series**", rather than the original.

I also did some searching, and it turns out, by "uniqueness of trigonometric series", the correct question to ask is

> Can a function $f$ be represented by more than one trigonometric series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{int}$, where $c_n$ are complex numbers?

Or equivalently,

> Can a trigonometric series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{int}$, where $c_n\neq 0$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, converge to the zero function?

The two problems seem to be exactly opposite to me. Is my understanding correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you even mean by “uniqueness of limit functions…”? No one here can comment on why they decided to name things a certain way, other than it makes sense (and I still don’t understand why you say it doesn’t or is misleading). If you want, you can even say more technically, the claim is that the Fourier series map $\mathcal{F}:L^1(T^n)\to C_0(\Bbb{Z}^n)$ is injective.

Comment: @peek-a-boo It seems to me "uniqueness of series" should mean "there can't be more than one series". But instead the emphasis in the book is "there can't be more than one function". If you want to emphasis that, shouldn't you say "uniqueness of functions"? 

But English is not my my native language, so there might be some weird misunderstanding on my part (and I apologize if so).

Comment: I suggest focusing on the theorem and not the section’s title.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Definitely. Although, just for the sake of it, perhaps "injectivity" might be better than "uniqueness" in this context. Anyhow, thanks for the comments.